# how can I add column in body Flutter that already have listtile?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I want to add a drop-down button after list view, and I saw a tutorial on youtube that the dropdown menu is inside the column, this is my code

```
 @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: ListView( 
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 50),
        children:<Widget>[
          
        
        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
        Text('Select Mall',
        style: TextStyle(  
          fontSize: 24,  
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,  
        ),),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),_buildMallPlaces(),

      ],
      
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to add the dropdown menu item after _buildMallPlaces(). Or anyone have any idea? thanks

Comment: Can you include an image that are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this ?

```
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 2, child: 
             ListView( 
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 50),
        children:<Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
        Text('Select Mall',
        style: TextStyle(  
          fontSize: 24,  
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,  
        ),),
        SizedBox(height: 20,),_buildMallPlaces(),

      ),],
      
      ), YOUR_DROPDOWN]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your column scrollable with a SingleChildSrollView.

If you want to add a ListView within your Column:

Wrap the ListView with a container & provide it with a height & width.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          const Text(
            'Select Mall',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ...List.generate(
              5, (items) => ListTile(title: Text('column item: $items'))),
          // _buildMallPlaces(),
         
          const Divider(color: Colors.red),
          const Text('container starts'),
          Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
              child: ListView.builder(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:12,horizontal:8),
                  itemCount: 20,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(title:Text('listview item: $index'));
                  })),
          const Text('Container ends'),

          const Divider(color: Colors.red),
           //your button goes here..
          Center(child:ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){print('button tapped');},
              child: const Align(
                alignment:Alignment.center,
                child:Text('tap me',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white))))),
          
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a demo, hope it helps!
https://codepen.io/shavar67/pen/zYRazEr